signed apk Issue, Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0
C:/Users/amanp/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/bf147c6cd7d9a84285a61be509aaadbb/transformed/jetified-firebase-messaging-24.0.0/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/com.google.firebase-firebase-messaging.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'

app level gradle

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' 
}

android {
    namespace 'com.aafes.kiosk'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aafes.kiosk"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        manifestPlaceholders = [requestLegacyExternalStorage: "true"]
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}


dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.7.0'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:4.0.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:24.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    def lottieVersion = "3.4.0"
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:$lottieVersion"

    //retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
//    //DropDown Menu...
//    implementation 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'
//    //picasso
//    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.8'
//    //location
//    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.2.0'
//    //loader
//    implementation 'com.agrawalsuneet.androidlibs:dotsloader:1.4'
    //rooms
    def room_version = "2.5.2"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'

    implementation 'com.github.angads25:toggle:1.1.0'

    implementation 'com.starmicronics:stario:2.11.2'
    implementation 'com.starmicronics:starioextension:1.15.2'
    implementation files('../libs/autoreplyprint.aar')
    implementation 'com.google.android.flexbox:flexbox:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.joielechong:countrycodepicker:2.4.2'
    implementation 'io.github.chaosleung:pinview:1.4.4'
}
 

**
I was trying to Generate a release apk with android studio.
App is compiling and running fine and Was also able to create apk with debug.
But when generating signed apk getting this error.**
